# Which will be the better database design in following situation? Why?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

First I would like to clear the scenario.

There is bulk mail system have lists(groups of emails) and every lists has multiple contacts(emails). the contacts have some states like normal,unsubscribed,bounced etc.

I am thinking to design something like this.

```
Table Contacts
-----------------------------------------
id    email   group_id contacts   status
-----------------------------------------
```

status will store the email ids states which is stated above.

But one list can have a thousands of email and so if the client increases, retrieving of data will be caused to performance issue

So I get the two solutions

1. To make the indexing for status column
2. to make a different table for different contact status like

   one table for normal added contacts
   another for unsubscribed contacts.
   and so on for other states

So my question is which will be the better solution for above situation.
Please guide me.

I am going to bind the lists and contacts in many to many relationship above table is just for describing the problem.
Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Queries for retrieving the information from above table

1. for retrieving normal contacts

   select * from contacts where group_id = '[group_id]' and status = 1
2. for unsubscribed contacts

   select * from contacts where group_id =[group_id]' and status = 2
   and so on.

Comment: why the question gets downvotes is there anything wrong.

Comment: I cannot speculate on the indexes you require unless I know the queries you are going to use.

Comment: @EdHeal The query for getting the list contacts will be select * from contacts where group_id = [group_id] and status = 1(for normal contacts).  and query for the listing unsubscribed contacts will be select * from contacts where group_id = [group_id] and status = 2(for unsubscribed contacts)

Comment: Put that as an edit in the question - It is kinda critical to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you comment put an index on `group_id` and `status`

i.e.

```
 create index my_index on contacts(group_id, status)
```

That will solve any performance problem as the database can find the list without locking the table.

Might be an idea to not perform any expensive operations whilst scanning that list (e.g. emailing)

Comment: what will be the problem with second approach?

Comment: Why have hassle of moving contacts from one table to another? It is not required

Comment: I am going to add the thousands of emails at a time in the database and also allows other basic crud operations

Comment: bcoz i read that indexing decreses the performance of insert update operations

Comment: Yes it does. But it increases performance on read. Surely most of the operations are read. If you are uploading tons of data do it at a quiet period (e.g. overnight) or perhaps break it down

Comment: None of this is in the original question BTW

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73518/discussion-between-siddhesh-and-ed-heal).